# Connection timeout in AzureML studio

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

I'm trying to connect a VM I have in AzureML studio.  I keep getting the following:  Connection attempt timed out for ''. Verify that server is accessible and SSH service is accepting connections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your VM config and test your connection through the 'connect' tab.  Is your test successful?  If not, check if port 22 is blocked.  Watch for automated blocking rules applied to your VM.

we have DSVM attach in preview - might be interesting for you: https://github.com/Azure/azureml-previews/tree/main/previews/dsvm-attach.